# Style acronyms long forms and avoid description fields for those that don't have it defined

Tags: xetex, formatting, glossaries, acronyms

I'm working with the `glossaries` package, and wanted to modify the `long-short` style of the glossary like this (edited, it didn't came from a .tex compilation):

[image: Idea with comments of what I'm trying to achieve]

For acronyms only (as the real document I'm working on needs to contain both acronyms and normal terms into a single glossary):

- Don't put any description if it doesn't have that tag defined in the optional argument, and put the short form of the acronym in bold, a line, and the long form in plain format, all of these in the same line (i.e. avoid any space for the description field).
- Otherwise, put the long form first, then the short form between parentheses, and the given description below (as in the `long-short` glossary style).

The following MWE shows what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeglossaries

% Style the acronyms
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\renewcommand*{\acronymsort}[2]{#1} % Order by short form
\renewcommand*{\acronymentry}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrydesc{#1}}{\glsentrylong{#1}}}{%
    \acronymfont{\glsentryshort{#1} --- \glsentrylong{#1}}%
  }{%
    \acronymfont{\glsentrylong{#1} (\glsentryshort{#1})}%
  }%
}

\newacronym{one}{one}{The number one}
\newacronym{two}{two}{The number two}
\newacronym[description={Just a number with a meaningful description}]{three}{three}{The number three}

\begin{document}
  The numbers \acrshort{one}, \acrshort{two} and \acrshort{three}...
  \setglossarystyle{altlisthypergroup}
  \printglossary[type=main]
\end{document}
```

- The glossary now shows both glossary terms and acronyms (as I'm not using the `acronym` option for the package).
- For acronyms, I managed to style the acronym long and short forms, according to the value of the description field (the documentation for the package states that the `long-short` style "copies" the acronym long form into the description field *if the user didn't define it*).

And the output of compiling the given code is:

[image: Output of compiling the MWE]

Is there a way to:

- avoid the description field for the acronyms that don't have it user-defined?
- change the long form for these acronyms to plain format?

Any help will be much appreciated `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be better off using the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package, which allows different abbreviation styles. This package internally loads `glossaries`, but there are some subtle differences. In particular it uses a completely different abbreviation mechanism. Each entry now has an associated category (set with the `category` key) and the abbreviation style is set for a particular category using:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[category-label]{style-name}
```

where `category-label` is the category label and `style-name` is the style. Abbreviations are then defined using `\newabbreviation`. This has the same syntax as `\newacronym`. To make it easier to transfer documents over from just the base `glossaries` package to `glossaries-extra`, `\newacronym` is redefined to internally use `\newabbreviation` (with `category=acronym`). The other difference is that the short form is obtained using `\glsxtrshort` instead of `\acrshort`. (This allows for different abbreviation fonts.)

So your MWE can be changed to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[withoutdesc]{short-long}
\setabbreviationstyle[withdesc]{long-short-desc}

\newabbreviation[category=withoutdesc]{one}{one}{The number one}
\newabbreviation[category=withoutdesc]{two}{two}{The number two}
\newabbreviation[category=withdesc,
 description={Just a number with a meaningful description}]
 {three}{three}{The number three}

\newglossarystyle{customlist}{%
  \setglossarystyle{listhypergroup}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
      \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]%
    \glsifcategory{##1}{withoutdesc}%
    { --- \glsentrylong{##1}}%
    {%
      \mbox{}\par\nobreak\csuse{@afterheading}%
      \glossentrydesc{##1}%
    }%
    \glspostdescription\space ##2%
  }%
}
\setglossarystyle{customlist}%

\begin{document}
The numbers \glsxtrshort{one}, \glsxtrshort{two} and \glsxtrshort{three}...

\printglossary[type=main]
\end{document}
```

This assigns two categories: `withdesc` for abbreviations with a description and `withoutdesc` for abbreviations without a description. This allows one style (`short-long`) to be applied to the abbreviations without a description and another style (`long-short-desc`) to be applied to the abbreviations with a description.

A new glossary style is also defined based on the `listhypergroup` style that checks the entry's category (using `\glsifcategory`) to determine whether or not to insert a paragraph break followed by the description.

I'm guessing that you've used `\acrshort` because you don't want expansion on first use. There are abbreviation styles that can automatically do this for you so that you can just use `\gls` instead.

In the first case (abbreviations with no descriptions), this can easily be achieved by replacing the `short-long` style with `short-nolong`:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[withoutdesc]{short-nolong}
```

For the `withdesc` category, there is a `short-nolong-desc` style but this would reverse the order in the `name` field. There isn't a `nolong-short-desc` style, but a style can be defined based on an existing style like this:

```
\newabbreviationstyle{nolong-short-desc}%
{% base it on short-nolong-desc:
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleSetup{short-nolong-desc}%
}%
{% base it on long-short style:
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short}%
}
```

Now the style can be set for the `withdesc` category:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[withdesc]{nolong-short-desc}
```

The complete document is now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newabbreviationstyle{nolong-short-desc}%
{% base it on short-nolong-desc:
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleSetup{short-nolong-desc}%
}%
{% base it on long-short style:
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short}%
}

\setabbreviationstyle[withoutdesc]{short-nolong}
\setabbreviationstyle[withdesc]{nolong-short-desc}

\newabbreviation[category=withoutdesc]{one}{one}{The number one}
\newabbreviation[category=withoutdesc]{two}{two}{The number two}
\newabbreviation[category=withdesc,
 description={Just a number with a meaningful description}]
 {three}{three}{The number three}

\newglossarystyle{customlist}{%
  \setglossarystyle{listhypergroup}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
      \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]%
    \glsifcategory{##1}{withoutdesc}%
    { --- \glsentrylong{##1}}%
    {%
      \mbox{}\par\nobreak\csuse{@afterheading}%
      \glossentrydesc{##1}%
    }%
    \glspostdescription\space ##2%
  }%
}
\setglossarystyle{customlist}%

\begin{document}
The numbers \gls{one}, \gls{two} and \gls{three}...

\printglossary[type=main]
\end{document}
```

The resulting document looks like:

[image: image of document]

You can provide your own shortcut command so that you don't need to keep setting the `category` key. For example:

```
% syntax: \mynewabbrv[options]{label}{short}{long}{description}
\newcommand*{\mynewabbrv}[5][]{%
  \ifblank{#5}%
  {\newabbreviation[category=withoutdesc,#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  {\newabbreviation[category=withdesc,description={#5},#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}

\mynewabbrv{one}{one}{The number one}{}
\mynewabbrv{two}{two}{The number two}{}
\mynewabbrv{three}{three}{The number three}
 {Just a number with a meaningful description}
```

This uses `etoolbox`'s `\ifblank` to determine if the final argument is empty.

Alternatively, if you want to keep your original syntax:

```
\makeatletter
\define@key{mynewabbrv}{description}{\def\mydesc{#1}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\newacronym}[4][]{%
  \def\mydesc{}%
  \setkeys*{mynewabbrv}{#1}%
  \ifdefempty{\mydesc}%
  {\newabbreviation[category=withoutdesc,#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  {\newabbreviation[category=withdesc,#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}

\newacronym{one}{one}{The number one}
\newacronym{two}{two}{The number two}
\newacronym[description={Just a number with a meaningful description}]
 {three}{three}{The number three}
```

This allows the `description` key to be extracted from the options list.

Comment: Wow. `o.o` I'm happy I finially could read this. It's really clear, educational, and even you showed me other ways to do the same! `:D` Definitely it was worth it. Thank you so much! `=)`